# Why do I need a server for practicing PHP?

Tags: php

I took a PHP course on a site called Codecademy.com, and I later learned that you needed a server to practice PHP independently. I don't want to host a server, because all I want to do is practice PHP. Why is this so?

Comment: You can run a server locally on your machine! :) Try https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.introduction.php

Comment: Use softwares such as wampserver or xampp server. They are free and for local use only

Comment: PHP really likes to run inside a web server because it began life as an HTML template system and mutated from there.

Comment: visit https://3v4l.org/ instead

Answer (score 1):

Your need for a "server" is really just a need for some kind of PHP runtime.  Since version 5.4, PHP [includes an integrated webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) for you to do just this kind of thing, so as long as you install a recent version of PHP you have everything you need.

Answer (score 1):

What You need to understand is that PHP is server-side.

That means if You open a php file without a server,

you will see the code, and not the result of php,

because PHP must be processed by PHP parser.

That's why You have to use a server, but You can open one locally, using a program such as:

[XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/pl/index.html)